# recording audio without MediaRecorder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There are bunch of sample codes to record audio using JavaScript.

But the issue is they use this line of code `rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);` and unfortunately this stops Web Speech API in android devices. I mean if you use the exact line of the above code the Web Speech API doesn't work anymore. Don't know why it's just what it is :(

So I'm looking for a solution to record the audio and not to use the `rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);`

Any suggestions or fix for this ?

Comment: I guess that you are getting an error in the console that you should fix

Comment: No Errors at all ..

Comment: Does it also stop Web Speech API on the desktop?

Comment: No, at all.... desktop is fine , I'm reproducing the issue and provide a codepen in a minute

Comment: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/GRddgYL?editors=1010

Comment: It indeed stops, but I would rather seek a solution instead of trying to find a replacement. I doubt you can record in any other way

Comment: Here is the post for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166961/recording-the-voice-and-speech-recognition-in-browser