# Recording voice and convert speech to text at the same time

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I want to use the Web Speech API for speech recognition and record the user's voice in Android Devices at the same time (I mean user holds a button, his/her voice is recorded and transcript to text at the same time .

This is working perfectly in Windows but with Android it just returns the error :

> no-speech

Seems like defining the `MediaRecorder` blocks access of microphone for Web Speech API in Android!

How can I fix this?

If I remove this line which is responsible for recording, speech recognition works again:

```
 new MediaRecorder(stream); // adding this line ruins the speech recognition
```

Here is the code in action:

In the given code I didn't remove this, in order to show that the code won't work on Android devices:

Note: this code should be tested with an Android device, it is working fine in desktop.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/GRddgYL?editors=1010

Demo here in SO:

```js
let audioChunks = [];
let rec;
let stopRecognize;
const output = document.getElementById('output');

async function Recognize() {
  console.log('Recognize')
    let recognitionAllowed = true;
    stopRecognize = function() {
        if(recognitionAllowed) {
            recognition.stop();
            recognitionAllowed = false; 
        }
    }

    var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var SpeechGrammarList = SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList;
    var SpeechRecognitionEvent = SpeechRecognitionEvent || webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent;
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
    recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
    recognition.lang = 'en-GB';
    recognition.continuous = false;
    recognition.interimResults = true;
    recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
    recognition.start();

    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        window.interim_transcript = '';
        window.speechResult = '';
        for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if(event.results[i].isFinal) {
                speechResult += event.results[i][0].transcript;
                console.log(speechResult);
                output.innerHTML = speechResult;
            } else {
                interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
                console.log(interim_transcript);
                output.innerHTML = interim_transcript;
            }
        }
    }

    recognition.onerror = function(event) {
        // restartRecognition();
        console.log('recognition error: ' + event.error);
    }

    recognition.onend = async function(event) { 
        restartRecognition();
    }

    function restartRecognition() {
        try { if(recognitionAllowed) recognition.start(); } catch(err) {}
    }

} 






const startRecognition = document.getElementById('start-recognition');
startRecognition.addEventListener('mousedown', handleRecognitionStart);
startRecognition.addEventListener('mouseup', handleRecognitionEnd);
startRecognition.addEventListener('touchstart', handleRecognitionStart);
startRecognition.addEventListener('touchend', handleRecognitionEnd);

function handleRecognitionStart(e) {
  console.log('handleRecognitionStart', isTouchDevice)
    const event = e.type;
    if(isTouchDevice && event == 'touchstart') {
        recognitionStart();
    } else if(!isTouchDevice && event == 'mousedown') {
      console.log('handleRecognitionStart')
        recognitionStart();
    }
}
const isTouchDevice = touchCheck();

function touchCheck() {
    const maxTouchPoints = navigator.maxTouchPoints || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
    return 'ontouchstart' in window || maxTouchPoints > 0 || window.matchMedia && matchMedia('(any-pointer: coarse)').matches; 
}


function handleRecognitionEnd(e) {
    const event = e.type;
  
    console.log(':::', event == 'touchend');
  
    if(isTouchDevice && event == 'touchend') {
        recognitionEnd();
    } else if(!isTouchDevice && event == 'mouseup') {
        recognitionEnd();
    }
}

function recognitionEnd() {
    resetRecognition();
}



function recognitionStart() {
  console.log('recognitionStart')
    Recognize();
    audioChunks = []; 
    voiceRecorder.start()
}

function resetRecognition() {
    console.log('reset')
    if(typeof stopRecognize == "function") stopRecognize();
    // if(rec.state !== 'inactive') rec.stop();
    voiceRecorder.stop()
}

const playAudio = document.getElementById('play');

playAudio.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('play');
  voiceRecorder.play();
  
})


class VoiceRecorder {
    constructor() {
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            console.log("getUserMedia supported")
        } else {
            console.log("getUserMedia is not supported on your browser!")
        }
        this.mediaRecorder
        this.stream
        this.playerRef = document.querySelector("#player")
        this.recorderRef = document.querySelector("#recorder")
        this.chunks = []
        this.isRecording = false
        this.constraints = {
            audio: true,
            video: false
        }
    }

    handleSuccess(stream) {
        this.stream = stream
        this.stream.oninactive = () => {
            console.log("Stream ended!")
        };
        this.recorderRef.srcObject = this.stream
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream)
        console.log(this.mediaRecorder)
        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.onMediaRecorderDataAvailable.bind(this)
        this.mediaRecorder.onstop = this.onMediaRecorderStop.bind(this)
        this.recorderRef.play()
        this.mediaRecorder.start()
    }

    handleError(error) {
        console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error)
    }
    
    onMediaRecorderDataAvailable(e) { this.chunks.push(e.data) }
    
    onMediaRecorderStop(e) { 
        const blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { 'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' })
        const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        this.playerRef.src = audioURL;
        this.chunks = [];
        this.stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        this.stream = null;
    }

    play() { this.playerRef.play(); }

    start() {
        console.log('start')
        if(this.isRecording) return;

        console.log('33')

        this.isRecording = true;
        this.playerRef.src = '';
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia(this.constraints)
            .then(this.handleSuccess.bind(this))
            .catch(this.handleError.bind(this))
    }
    
    stop() {
        if(!this.isRecording) return;
        this.isRecording = false;
        this.recorderRef.pause();
        this.mediaRecorder.stop();
    }
    
}

voiceRecorder = new VoiceRecorder();
```

```html
<button id="start-recognition">Hold This Button and Speak In Android This should output the text and record your voice at the s</button>

<button id="play">Play Recorded Audio</button>

<h1 id="output">Voice over here</h1>


<audio id="recorder" muted hidden></audio>
<audio id="player" hidden></audio>
```

Comment: only one of them can access mic at same time. So you can try to record as a stream and use the recording for transcription. check google real time captioning.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chrome on Windows PCs does allow concurrent usage of the microphone. Therefore to provide the most graceful experience for the user, what you can do is use a tool like `ua-parser-js` to check if the user has the correct device-browser combination and do simultaneous processing otherwise use a step by step approach like: *Record first and recognize later*.

That being said I'm not certain if any of the mobile device browsers could be forced (or tricked) to allow the usage of the microphone by multiple APIs via Dedicated Web Workers. It would be very interesting to know which ones do if they do.